# PHP. 7.4 built-in server handle multiple requests?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

From 7.4+ onwards, I assume PHP built in server is capable of handling multiple incoming requests, up to and equal to the environment variable: `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS`

I have a web app which is composed of a couple dozen AJAX powered lists, on the first page load, using the built-in server it slows to a crawl, usually fails due to timeout in PHP scripts.

I read the above feature, added environment variable (PHP is a docker container), and shell'ed into my container, did a `top/ps` I can now see X number of PHP processes:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                 
    1 root      20   0  722864  21932  14448 S   0.3  1.1   0:09.91 symfony                                                                                                 
   20 root      20   0  210892  48188  36544 S   0.0  2.4   0:00.79 php7.4                                                                                                  
   21 root      20   0  205676  33460  24500 S   0.0  1.6   0:00.22 php7.4                                                                                                  
   22 root      20   0  208212  40908  29640 S   0.0  2.0   0:00.42 php7.4                                                                                                  
   23 root      20   0  210644  42236  30836 S   0.0  2.1   0:00.61 php7.4                                                                                                  
   24 root      20   0  208764  40784  31176 S   0.0  2.0   0:01.14 php7.4                                                                                                  
   25 root      20   0  205804  33588  24508 S   0.0  1.6   0:00.22 php7.4     
...
```

I am using Symfony to start a dev server, but no matter what I do none of the processes seem to be carrying any of the load? What am I missing?

I switched to the built-in PHP server about 2 years ago, from NGINX. It made my vagrant setup easier (now docker) but my performance took a hit, which I've dealt with. I'd like to improve the responsiveness of the app using this approach if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: I quote the warning from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php): _"Warning: This web server is designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.
"_

Comment: This isn't a production system. It is a symfony dev environment. I read thru the manual carefully on this section. It seems it handle a few concurrent requests but more than five or so it seems to hang and not delegate the requests to workre threads. I was hoping I missed something but maybe not?

Comment: I always assumed that "The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked." means that only one request could be processed at a time.  I would also assume that PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS is about command line interfaces though I never messed with it before.

Comment: Have you verified if it works as expected in Nginx? It could well happen that it's something in your codebase what's making concurrent requests wait.